# Why isn't the class that I define correctly reading in android studio and showing errors?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, compiler-errors

I created an Android application and at this point I was getting errors on using **[DataBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding)** but in the Run process it is working properly .

I was solving this problem by clicking on **Rebuild Project** from the Build menu and also choosing **Clean Project** and now it has no benefit this way.

But now it gives me errors on the **Model Class** on the Method getter that I created before as shown in the picture below.

> Note: Class **FCM** I am creating a static method `sendNotificationToTopic()`, and I also have this
> problem with all project that I am creating.

This imports code :

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.madeveloper.kayilarcarpetadmin.R;
import com.madeveloper.kayilarcarpetadmin.adapter.DescriptionOrderAdapter;
import com.madeveloper.kayilarcarpetadmin.databinding.ActivityDescriptionOrderBinding;
import com.madeveloper.kayilarcarpetadmin.model.CartItem;
import com.madeveloper.kayilarcarpetadmin.model.Order;
import com.madeveloper.kayilarcarpetadmin.model.Product;
import com.madeveloper.kayilarcarpetadmin.util.Constant;
import com.madeveloper.kayilarcarpetadmin.util.Util;
import com.madeveloper.kayilarcarpetadmin.util.FCM;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
```

And thanks in advance for help.

[image]

Comment: can you show your imports?

Comment: that should do it, Could be something in your FCM class if you can include the FCM class too :d

Comment: @ahmednader Can you explain to me more that I do not understand what you mean?

Comment: I mean can you show your FCM class too from the very first line which is the package name?